# How to link a domain to a subdomain with DNS / A record?

Tags: dns, ip-address, subdomain

Ok, there are a lot of topics regarding this, but there is no detailed solution..

I bought a domain www.newsite.com but my webspace is at a different hoster and there in a subdomain (www.oldsite.com/subdomain or www.subdomain.oldsite.com)

I can now change the DNS but I have to enter an IP. I have the IP of www.oldsite.com, but by doing that I just link to the root of www.oldsite.com. What I need is the IP of the subdomain, which is the same, I think. Something like [IP]/subdomain does not work, I just can enter number.

So, I have to specify a IP for the subdomain, right? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The IP for the subdomain is the same as the IP for the domain. However you also have to set up your hosting so that it knows to send www.newsite.com to the subdomain. How you do that depends on your hosting. Are you using cPanel or some other way of managing your hosting?